# Cannot use “Precompile during publishing” website when uncheck "Allow precompiled site to be updatable"

Tags: asp.net, publishing, precompile

I am trying to publish my web app.
Here is a picture of my setting for my publishing profile: 
[image]

As you can see, I have the "Precompile during publishing" option checked.

Here is the Configuration settings for "Precompile during publish".

[image]

I unchecked to "Allow precompiled site to be updatable" option.

I get error when publish with above setting.

> Error ASPPARSE: Unknown server tag 'uc1:ctrlAbcxyz'.

Please give solutions or how to fix this issue.
P/S: uncheck "Allow precompiled site to be updatable" option is requied.

Update: I changed Precompile Setting follow @Sunil recommenend:

[image]

but I still get a error: > Error ASPPARSE: Unknown server tag 'uc1:ctrlAbcxyz'.

Comment: Did you try to Rebuild your web app to see if any compilation errors were there? You will not be able to publish if there are compilation errors.

Comment: @Sunil: when i rebuild my web app, it's success without error.

Comment: Try with the option  Allow precompiled site to be updateable?

Comment: @Sunil: if I checked  Allow precompiled site to be updateable option, it work ok, but I would like to compile without updateable.

Comment: You cannot allow site to be updateable  with a single assembly.   Updateable site means you can change page markup by deploying individual  pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should not select the last Merge option, which is used only if web app is updateable according to following documentation at: [Publish dialog documentation at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Merge all pages and control outputs to a single assembly
>   This setting corresponds to the –w assemblyname option of the aspnet_merge.exe command.
>
> This option enables you to update UI elements separately from updating
>   other code. Special folders such as App_Code, App_WebReferences, and
>   so on are each compiled into a separate assembly. Specify the target
>   assembly name in the Assembly name box.

You should select the option of merging all outputs into one assembly.

Comment: you mean that, i should select third option: "Merge all outputs to a single assembly", right?

Comment: I changed to that option, but I get another error:Type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe' is not defined. When i used iframe control n user control.

Comment: That is a compilation error. Try Rebuilding your project and make sure no errors are there at end of Rebuilding.

Comment: Rebuild All is succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped. But error till happen.

Comment: What Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: Did you check Treat as a library?  That should be checked also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163693/discussion-between-luc-le-and-sunil).

Comment: I am using VS 2015 Enterprise. Yes I did check Treat option.